# How to send two emails to two different users? Resend.com

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, next.js, resend.com

I am using resend.com to try and send an email with different variables to two different users.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { EmailTemplate } from "../../components/emails/EmailTemplate";
import { Resend } from "resend";
import { supabase } from "../../../initSupabase";

const resend = new Resend(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RESEND_KEY);

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    const { player1, player2, player1Email, player2Email } = req.body;

    const player1Data = await resend.emails.send({
      from: "Acme <onboarding@resend.dev>",
      to: [player1Email],
      subject: "Hello player 1",
      react: EmailTemplate({ firstName: player1, secondName: player1Email }),
    });

    const player2Data = await resend.emails.send({
      from: "Acme <onboarding@resend.dev>",
      to: [player2Email],
      subject: "Hello player 2",
      react: EmailTemplate({ firstName: player2, secondName: player2Email }),
    });

    res.status(200).json({ player1Data, player2Data });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json(error);
  }
};
```

This sends to player1 but not to player2 even though the emails are correct for both. How can I send both emails to both users?

Their api allows you to send up to 50 emails by passing an array of strings into 'to' but this is not ideal as it means both parties can see each others email https://resend.com/docs/api-reference/emails/send-email

Comment: Do you get any error? What is return from the API call?

Comment: There are no errors in the resend.com logs, just 200 for the first player,  but nothing for the second

Comment: You may want to sent to both at the same time in the bcc field

Comment: Thanks grekier the issue was I hadn't paid for a subscription, test emails were only being sent to my registered email.

Answer (score 0):

i guess its already late to answer you as its been 5months already about this question.

But for the people who are still learning and searching for this query!

here:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { Resend } from 'resend';
import { EmailTemplate } from "../../components/emails/EmailTemplate";

const resend = new Resend(process.env.RESEND_API_KEY);

export async function POST(req) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { player1, player2, player1Email, player2Email } = req.json();

    try {
      const { player1Data } = await resend.emails.send({
        from: "Acme <onboarding@resend.dev>",
        to: [player1Email],
        subject: "Hello player 1",
        text: '',
        react: EmailTemplate({ firstName: player1, secondName: player1Email })
      });

      const { player2Data } = await resend.emails.send({
        from: "Acme <onboarding@resend.dev>",
        to: [player2Email],
        subject: "Hello player 2",
        text: '',
        react: EmailTemplate({ firstName: player2, secondName: player2Email })
      });
      return NextResponse.json({player1Data, player2Data});
    } catch (error) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error });
    }
  }

  return NextResponse.error(new Error('Invalid method'));
}
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.